# Is messaging other objects initiated from the same archive really safe?

Tags: ios, swift

The documentation of awakeFromNib(), https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1402907-awakefromnib, specifies

> Because the order in which objects are instantiated from an archive is
>   not guaranteed, your initialization methods should not send messages
>   to other objects in the hierarchy. **Messages to other objects can be**
>   **sent safely from within an awakeFromNib method**.

Is it really the case that messages to other objects can be sent safely from within an awakeFromNib method? Though all the objects within the same archive are initialized when an awakeFromNib method is called, the order of the callings of the awakeFromNib method on objects in an archive is not guaranteed, and the execution of the awakeFromNib method of an object can alter the object's value. How can messaging another object in an awakeFromNib method really be safe if we don't know if the other object has executed the awakeFromNib method? Is the documentation wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation means that it is "safe" to message other objects (from the archive) in the sense that all objects in the archive will have been instantiated before *any* object's `awakeFromNib` is called.  In other words it is guaranteed that the target object instance that you may want to message *exist* and their properties have been set as per any archived values or values specified by their initialisers.

I think you are asking "what if my `awakeFromNib` code alters the objects in some way and since I don't know the order of execution, is it "safe" to message other objects then?".

In this case you need to code so that the order of `awakeFromNib` invocation doesn't matter.  This may mean performing operations in some other function.

This doesn't mean that the documentation is incorrect.  Messaging other objects in `awakeFromNib` is generally "safe" but constraints you have put in place by mutating the object graph or object properties in `awakeFromNib` may mean that you don't get the desired outcome.

It is your responsibility to ensure that any state that *doesn't come from the nib itself* is either irrelevant or catered for.

Comment: I agree with you that the documentation is not incorrect in the strict sense that other objects are initialized when a `awakeFromNib` method is executed, and it is OK to message an other object in this situation. However, I think it could be incorrect in a more general sense. In the situation which one has to use an customized object, from another developer, with an `awakeFromNib` method that modifies this object after its initialization. If my object accesses this object in its `awakeFromNib` method, it can get different results depending on if this object's `awakeFromNib` has been executed.

Comment: I don't get some meaning of your last paragraph. I am sorry if I missed anything important.

Comment: You asked if the documentation is incorrect.  I am saying that it isn't, within the scope it is addressing.  The documentation refers to the "safety" of referencing some other object in `awakeFromNib` vs it being unsafe to reference some other object in an initialiser; when `awakeFromNib` is called then the object graph is complete with respect to the objects that are in the archive (or specifically the nib or storyboard scene) and their properties, *as stored in the archive*.

Comment: Of course nothing can be said about the "safety" with reference to some other objects that are not contained in the archive or mutation of the objects in the archive that is performed in an object's `awakeFromNib` method, but this is generally true of any function; `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` etc.; only you know how your code behaves in the broader sense.